# AWS EBS reservation pricing

Tags: aws-ebs

We are running EC2 instance with 1.5TB storage (EBS) attached. We are now about to reserve EC2 instance to get the lower price. Does the discount on reservation exist on EBS price as well?

I found information about discounts on EC2 reservation, but could not find if that discount refers to the whole EC2, together with attached EBS? Or is there no discount on reserved EBS?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 5):

EBS does not have reserved pricing like reserved ec2 instances.

**NOTE:** You are charged for storage allocated whether your instance is running or not.

#### References

- See more about pricing here: [Amazon EBS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/)