# How to purchase AWS EBS for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

New to AWS and just purchased a reserve instance but it only comes with 8GB of storage. And during the purchase there was no options to purchase storage or what AWS called EBS. Would anyone share your experience how to add storage to the reserve instance?
I can't find any purchase options under Elastic Block Store.

Thanks in advance
LHLK

Comment: Related, possibly still valid, answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648545/aws-ebs-reservation-pricing

Comment: Reserved instance is related to the EC2 instance type regardless of the storage

Comment: Thank you guys. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a new instance, there's an option to set up the storage, it's possible that you've missed it. Default is 8 GB.

Now, you have 2 options:

1. Increase the size of the already attached volume
2. Create and attach a new volume

In both cases, you would go to EC2 -> volumes

Option 1:

- Select the volume that's attached to your instance
- In the upper right, click Actions -> Modify Volume
- There you can set up the new size
- Based on OS, you will have to follow OS-specific steps to increase the file system size: [Extend a file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Option 2:

- Click on a `Create Volume` button in the upper right
- Set up the details (make sure the volume is in the same availability zone as the EC2 instance
- When volume is ready, select it, click on Actions -> Attach Volume
- Choose your EC2 instance
- Based on OS, you will have to follow OS-specific steps to increase the file system size: [Extend a file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Comment: Hey thanks. I didn't start the instance yet because you know try to save as much as I can. I will make note to your answer and I think it will be better to allocate bigger size when lanuching a new instance just to bypass adding disk volumn.